Images are not displayed in flutter web
I have a question because I have an unresolved problem.
I'm trying to get an image url from another web page's html source (e.g. img src) and use it as a thumbnail on my web page.
Image.network("https://cdn2.ppomppu.co.kr/zboard/data3/2024/0612/20240612153148_6FinzEg08D.jpg")

But when I add and run it, no image is displayed and it says [object event].
object event
I tried the following:

Specify rendering as HTML when building.
Add options to index.html

<script type="text/javascript">
   window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
</script>

Even if you set and run the above two options, the result is the same.
The message displayed on the console is as follows.
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following Event$ object was thrown resolving an image frame:
  [object Event]

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

Image provider:
  NetworkImage("https://cdn2.ppomppu.co.kr/zboard/data3/2024/0612/20240612153148_6FinzEg08D.jpg",
  scale: 1.0)
Image key:
  NetworkImage("https://cdn2.ppomppu.co.kr/zboard/data3/2024/0612/20240612153148_6FinzEg08D.jpg",
  scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

However, in the 'flutter web' project, the problem occurs as above,
It displays normally in 'flutter app'.
Is there any solution?

That server isn't supplying any CORS headers, so naturally it is not going to work. You may be able to administer the server so that it supplies them. Otherwise, you will have to bounce/proxy the requests through your own web server that's hosting your Flutter app. (Note that during development, you server will need to emit CORS headers, if you go for the second approach.)

the error you faced may be due to the "cross origin resource sharing issue".
To troubleshoot this error you can

use a different image url to check
use a placeholder to load a different image when the actual image does not loads
instead of directly using the Image.network you should parse the image url, store in a variable and then display form the variable

for e.g.
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Uint8List> fetchImage(String url) async {
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
return response.bodyBytes;
}


// In your build method
FutureBuilder<Uint8List>(
future: fetchImage('https://cdn2.ppomppu.co.kr/zboard/data3/2024/0612/20240612153148_6FinzEg08D.jpg'),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
} else {
return CircularProgressIndicator();
}
},
)

